# How can I make same size canvas for all different size of ios devices , canvas has elements like text and stickers - swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

In storyboard, Container view has Background imageview which is inside UIScrollView and container view has another view on top of uiscrollview which is holding all text elements (UItextviews) and stickers(UIImageviews),
So to save on single device as draft canvas , I save frames of all elements (Text and stickers) into plist and while opening the canvas - I set all frames back. here I am not using any constraints.
Problem that I am facing when I share the same canvas from smaller device to big size device - canvas does not look the same as previous device as device size changes. Background image size also gets change.

Check the images attached for storyboard and canvas

[image: Canvas]

[image: Storyboard]

Does anyone has done like this before ?

Comment: *"I am not using any constraints"* -- so, first question, why not? Auto-layout and constraints can handle all of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo for canvas image code:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
```

`.fillReact` function will make those changes up for you ... you have to just create a function that is taking device ratio and resizing those parameters as you want to.

Comment: canvas is the view containing the background image and the elements on top of the image combine.